# What is the problem with infinite current in ideal circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, conductors, electromagnetic-induction

For Some time forget about practical situation. Take an ideal situation. 
When there is a magnetic field changing in a coil there is electric field induced inside wire. If the wire is perfectly conducting, then there is a infinite current. So there is no electric field in the circuit.
But think in another way: what if there is a infinite current in the ideal conductor? Why infinite current not exist in a ideal conductor.

Comment: your question is not clear, maybe a diagram would help. are you aware of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity

Comment: are you talking about superconductors?

Answer (score 0):

In theory the potential (voltage) is indeterminate as $V=IR$ gives zero times infinity This means the energy in and out are both indeterminate. In practice, an infinite answer means your model has reached the limit of its usefulness.